# Passing controller calculation logic to view with ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, viewbag

I have a controller that runs some calculation on data, and then I need to return the calculation to a view.  I understand that I can accomplish this through the `ViewBag`, but I would like to know the best practice for doing this.  Are these `LINQ` queries something that should just be executed in the `View`?

```
public ViewResult Results()
{
    var surveyresponsemodels = db.SurveyResponseModels.Include(
        s => s.SurveyProgramModel).Include(s => s.PersonModel);

    ViewBag.PatientFollowUpResult = db.SurveyResponseModels.Count(
        r => r.PatientFollowUp);

    ViewBag.ChangeCodingPractice = db.SurveyResponseModels.Count(
        r => r.ChangeCodingPractice);

    ViewBag.CountTotal = db.SurveyResponseModels.Count();

    return View(surveyresponsemodels.ToList());
 }
```

Comment: If I were you, I would create a viewmodel that the view would consume. I would not do the calculation in the view. Yeah, what gdoron said...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best practice is not using `ViewBag` at all.

Put all the data you want you want to use in the View in your **ViewModel**.

Keep the View clean for calculations, and use it only for presentations.

Comment: I guess the part where I'm confused is that I want to display the data only from a single model (rather than combining multiple models), but I just want to perform some calculations on that model and send the calculations back to the view.  Create a viewmodel with these calculations, won't I essentially be storing the calculations in a database and retrieving with a viewModel?

Comment: @user547794. You can create a big model with small models inside of it. That is the best way. Though you can write LINQ and a lot of C# code inside the View, it's deprecated.